# Django queryset not returning distinct values

Tags: django, sqlite, django-queryset

I have a query that for some reason is not returning distinct values even though I have specified distinct, I thought it may be because of the only, so I removed that, but the list is still the same

```
circuit_providers =  CircuitInfoData.objects.only('provider').values('provider').distinct()
```

I just want a list of unqiue providers

model.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
import string
import random
import time
import os

# Create your models here.
from service.models import ServiceContacts

def site_photos_path(instance, filename):
    file ,extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    random_string = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(6))
    filename = '%s-%s%s' % (random_string,time.strftime("%d-%m-%H-%M-%S"),extension)
    return 'site_photos/{0}'.format(filename)

def service_upload_path(instance, filename):
    file ,extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    random_string = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(6))
    filename = '%s-%s%s' % (random_string,time.strftime("%d-%m-%H-%M-%S"),extension)
    return 'service_files/{0}'.format(filename)    

def site_files_path(instance, filename):
    file ,extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    random_string = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(6))
    filename = '%s-%s%s' % (random_string,time.strftime("%d-%m-%H-%M-%S"),extension)
    return 'site_files/{0}'.format(filename)   

provider_choices = (
        ('KCOM','KCOM'),
        ('BT','BT'),
        ('EE','EE'),
        ('THREE','THREE'),
    ) 
circuit_choices = (
        ('DSL','DSL'),
        ('VDSL','VDSL'),
        ('MPLS','MPLS'),
        ('4G','4G'),
        ('Internet Leased Line','Internet Leased Line'),
    )     

subnet_mask_choices = (
        ('/16','/16'),
        ('/24','/24'),
        ('/25','/25'),
        ('/26','/26'),
        ('/27','/27'),
        ('/28','/28'),
        ('/29','/29'),
        ('/30','/30'),
        ('/31','/31'),
    )       

class ShowroomConfigData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
    r1_loopback_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',verbose_name="R1 Loopback IP")
    r2_loopback_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',verbose_name="R2 Loopback IP")  
    opening_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Showroom opening date")
    last_hw_refresh_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of latest hardware refresh")
    is_showroom = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name="Is this site a showroom?")

    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Showroom Data"
            verbose_name_plural = "Showroom Data"  
            ordering = ('location',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.location   


class MajorSiteInfoData(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    major_subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',verbose_name="Major Site Subnet")
    routed_subnet = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',verbose_name="Routed Link Subnet")
    bgp_as = models.CharField(max_length=6,verbose_name="BGP AS Number")

    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Major Site Data"
            verbose_name_plural = "Major Site Data"      

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.location

class CircuitInfoData(models.Model):    
    showroom_config_data = models.ForeignKey(ShowroomConfigData,verbose_name="Install Showroom")
    major_site_info = models.ForeignKey(MajorSiteInfoData,verbose_name="Install Site") 
    circuit_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=circuit_choices)    
    circuit_speed = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    circuit_bearer = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=provider_choices)
    ref_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Reference No")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Circuit Data"
        verbose_name_plural = "Circuit Data"
        ordering = ('showroom_config_data__location','circuit_speed')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s | %s | %s' % (self.showroom_config_data.location,self.major_site_info.location, self.provider, self.service_type, self.ref_no)
```

results from shell below

```
[root@network-tools infternal]# python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from networks.models import CircuitInfoData
>>> d = CircuitInfoData.objects.values('provider').distinct()
>>> for item in d:
...  print item
...
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'KCOM'}
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'KCOM'}
.....
>>> print d.query
SELECT DISTINCT "networks_circuitinfodata"."provider", "networks_showroomconfigdata"."location", "networks_circuitinfodata"."circuit_speed" FROM "networks_circuitinfodata" INNER JOIN "networks_showroomconfigdata" ON ("networks_circuitinfodata"."showroom_config_data_id" = "networks_showroomconfigdata"."id") ORDER BY "networks_showroomconfigdata"."location" ASC, "networks_circuitinfodata"."circuit_speed" ASC
>>>
```

one thing ive noticed is that when i print items in shell as above

```
#### with def __unicode__(self): #####

>>> from networks.models import CircuitInfoData
>>> d = CircuitInfoData.objects.only('provider').distinct()
>>> for i in d:
...  print i
...
Location1 | Showroom | BT | DSL | N/A
Location2 | Showroom | BT | MPLS | XXXX
Location2 | Showroom | KCOM | MPLS | XXXX
Location3 | Showroom | BT | MPLS | XXXX
Location3 | Showroom | BT | DSL | N/A
Location4 | Showroom | KCOM | MPLS | XXXXX
...

#### with out def __unicode__(self): #####

>>> from networks.models import CircuitInfoData
>>> d = CircuitInfoData.objects.only('provider').distinct()
>>> for i in d:
...  print i
...
CircuitInfoData_Deferred_circuit_bearer_circuit_cfb3d62ef325a6acfc8ddcb43c8ae1c6 object
CircuitInfoData_Deferred_circuit_bearer_circuit_cfb3d62ef325a6acfc8ddcb43c8ae1c6 object
CircuitInfoData_Deferred_circuit_bearer_circuit_cfb3d62ef325a6acfc8ddcb43c8ae1c6 object
CircuitInfoData_Deferred_circuit_bearer_circuit_cfb3d62ef325a6acfc8ddcb43c8ae1c6 object
CircuitInfoData_Deferred_circuit_bearer_circuit_cfb3d62ef325a6acfc8ddcb43c8ae1c6 object
CircuitInfoData_Deferred_circuit_bearer_circuit_cfb3d62ef325a6acfc8ddcb43c8ae1c6 object
...

#### with either ####

>>> for i in d:
...  print i.provider
...
BT
BT
KCOM
BT
BT
KCOM
...
```

Comment: You could use `print circuit_providers.query` to show the raw query and see what's going on with the sql statement, maybe run the raw sql in your database shell and verify it.

Comment: @ShangWang ive added the output, it doesnt even look like its added a group by statement...

Comment: Which database backend do you use? `Model.values('field_name').distinct()` works fine with PostgreSQL. There might be differences in other backends. And which version of Django? This looks like a bug.

Comment: sqlite3, django 1.9

Comment: SQLite is great, but there's quite a few database features in django that are only available with PostgreSQL. My impression is that the psql backend also have fewer bugs. Probably because that's what most advanced sites are using in production, so more effort goes into reporting and fixing issues.

Comment: is this the procedure to follow to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL? http://matthewwittering.com/blog/how-to-migrating-the-database-engine-for-django.html

Comment: have you seen the latest edit, regarding the __unicode__(self)?

Comment: no it has nothing to do with that either. **did you use values('provider')?**

Comment: The query you have printed does not match with the output printed {'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'KCOM'}
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'BT'}
{'provider': u'KCOM'}
{'provider': u'BT'} which definitely shows that you are not running the query that you claim to be running or the query that I recommended.

Comment: i am using the exact syntax you have posted

Comment: @e4c5 posted output directly from shell into question

Comment: bah, what do i do now lol, is there any other way i can get round this do you know if?

Comment: what you mean unmanaged?

Comment: Just look up django unmanaged table. But if you are not aware of it, it probably isn't unamanaged but I think you should post your full model. clearly there is something missing here. I repeat that there is no way that your ORM query can produce that SQL query under normal circumstances. That inner join is out of this world

Comment: ok, ive added the model and some more debug i did

Comment: On revisiting this, I can reconfirm that you are seeing this error probably because you are using only() instead of values()!

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) says

> Returns a new QuerySet that uses SELECT DISTINCT in its SQL query.
> This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.
>
> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice,
> this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as
> Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result
> rows.

Distinct gives you distinct rows but you are looking at only one of the fields in the record and in that field items can be duplicated unless it has a unique constraint on it. And in this case you don't.

If you happen to be using postgresql you can do

```
CircuitInfoData.objects.distinct('provider')
```

to achieve your objective.

**UPDATE:**
Since you mentioned in the comments that you use sqlite, use this solution.

```
CircuitInfoData.objects.values('provider').distinct()
```

This will work because now each row has only one column. the resulting query will be similar to

```
SELECT DISTINCT "someapp_circuitinfodata"."name" FROM "someapp_circuitinfodata"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Notice that you have overridden the `__unicode__` function.

```
def __unicode__(self):
     return '%s | %s | %s | %s | %s' % 
       (self.showroom_config_data.location,self.major_site_info.location, 
       self.provider, self.service_type, self.ref_no)
```

You are referring to the fields in the related model. This is going to be very costly (unless you use `select_related`). Also note that if you iterate through a queryset and use print for debug purposes it will give you misleading results (since what you are seeing is the output of `__unicode__`, a rather complex function)

Comment: this gives me NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: Only psql supports arguments to `distinct`. So with other backends you can do. `CircuitInfoData.objects.values('provider').distinct()`, however, that seems to be broken in this case.

Comment: @HåkenLid I made a copy paste mistake when posting that answer. The correct is indeed of the form you posted in your comment. Which I have just reconfirmed by testing.

Comment: please see latest update, showing it not working again

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite, the solution is to use set(). Check the example below.

```
queryset = set(CircuitInfoData.objects.values_list('provider', flat=True).filter(provider__icontains='keyword'))
```

You can also do:

```
queryset = set(CircuitInfoData.objects.values_list('provider', flat=True))
```